# Is there a way to have one array that holds other arrays in c?

Tags: c

I have 4 int arrays. They all have the same number of elements. Something like this:

```
int  ar1[] = {1,2,3,4};
int  ar2[] = {10,12,13,14};
int  ar3[] = {8,9,15,16};
int  ar4[] = {17,18,19,20};
int  big[][] ={ar1,ar2,ar3,ar4};  // I know this is messed up but here is where the question lies
```

Is there a way so that when I run a for loop:

```
int i;
for(i =0; i<4; i++){
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x<4; x++){
       printf(big[i][x]); // something like this   
    }
}
```

So that when this is executed, it prints out:

Array 1 : 1 2 3 4
Array 2 : 10 12 13 14
etc.....

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out: [Multidimensional arrays in C](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9.html) and [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Multidimensional_arrays) for the general information on multidimensional arrays in C.

Your code should work with this:

```
int* big[] = {ar1, ar2, ar3, ar4};
```

Answer (score 1):

A C 2-dimensional array is nothing more or less than an array of arrays.  Such a 2-d array cannot be "ragged", i.e., each row must have the same number of elements.  For your particular case, you could declare it as:

```
int big[4][4] =
    { { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
      { 10, 12, 13, 14 },
      { 8, 9, 15, 16 },
      { 17, 18, 19, 20 } };
```

You can omit the first dimension: `int big[][4] = ...` and the length will be determined by the initializer, but you can't omit the second one.

One advantage of this approach is that it's a single object, and you can use `sizeof` to determine how many elements it has:

```
sizeof big == 16 * sizeof (int)
sizeof big[0] == sizeof *big == 4 * sizeof (int)
sizeof big[0][0] == sizeof (int)
```

But the disadvantage is that the dimensions are fixed.

Another approach is to use an array of pointers, where each pointer points to the first element of an array:

```
int row0[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int row1[] = { 10, 12, 13, 14 };
int row2[] = { 8, 9, 15, 16 };
int row3[] = { 17, 18, 19, 20 };

int *big[4] = { row0, row1, row2, row3 };
```

(In the initializer, `row0` is an array name, but it decays to a pointer to the first element; likewise for `row1`, `row2`, and `row3`).  This is more flexible, but you have to keep track of the number of elements in each row; `sizeof big[0]` will give you the size of a pointer, not of the row itself.

Yet another approach is make `big` a pointer-to-pointer:

```
int row0[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int row1[] = { 10, 12, 13, 14 };
int row2[] = { 8, 9, 15, 16 };
int row3[] = { 17, 18, 19, 20 };

int *rows[] = { row0, row1, row2, row3 };

int **big = rows;
```

This is even more flexible (and in practice you'd probably allocate everything with `malloc()`.

A fourth approach, probably not terribly useful, would be to make `big` an array of pointers to arrays; I won't go into the details of that.

Due to the array-to-pointer decay rules, even though `big` is of 4 different types in the 4 different cases, you can use the same syntax to refer to the `int` elements: `big[x][y]`.

Recommended reading, as always: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and you're pretty close to having it.  In C, what you do is construct (always) a bunch of adresses, and either you or the compiler does the necessary arithmetic to treat is as however many dimensions you want.

So, let's say we make a one-dimensional array, a vector:

```
int vec[] = {0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

In memory, that becomes a location with a name `vec`

```
vec:
     DS  0
     DS  1
     DS  2
     DS  3
```

where `DS` is just saying "define storage and initialize with".

When you write a `for` loop to iterate through it:

```
int ix;
for(ix=0; ix < 4; ix++){
   printf("%d\n", vec[ix]);
}
```

it becomes a loop somewhat like

```
ix:    DS 0
loop:  CMP ix, 4
       JGE end     ; jump if comparison is >=
       PUSH vec+ix ; address arithmetic
       JSR PRINTF  ; call the printf routing using value on the stack
       INC ix      ; ix := ix+1
       JUMP loop   ; goto top
end:
```

(That's in no particular assembler, just a pseudocode.)

Now, let's make a 2d array

```
int ary2[][] = {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7});
int ix, jx;
for(ix=0; ix<4;ix++){
   for(jx=0; jx<4; jx++){
      printf("%d\n", ary2[ix][jx]);
   }
}
```

In memory, that just becomes

```
ary2:
     DS 0
     DS 1
     DS 2
     DS 3
     DS 4
     DS 5
     DS 6
     DS 7
```

in other words, just another blob of memory.  Our loop becomes

```
ix:   DS  0
jx:   DS  0
;; Now, the compiler helps us a little bit: it "remembers" that
;; the inner array is 4 long.  We'll keep that around as 'len'
len:  DS  4
ofst: DS  0   ; and we'll keep a convenient variable for the "offset"
;; here's out loop
loop1:
      CMP ix, 4
      JGE end1
loop2:
      CMP  jx, 4
      JGE  end2
;; I'm going to cheat here.  ASSUME I've got a little
;; routine that multiplies ix*len and puts it in offset
      MLTOFFSET  ix,len
      ADD  jx, ofst
;; so what this all did was make ofst == (ix*len)+jx
      PUSH ary2+ofst
      INC  jx
      JUMP loop2
end2:
      INC ix
      JUMP loop1
end1:
```

If you walk through that, what you find is that `ary2[ix][jx]` turns into
`ary2+0`,`ary2+1`,`ary2+2`,...`ary2+6`,`ary2+7` -- and those are exactly the values you need to make that one piece of memory *act* like a 2 dimensional array.

The same trick, of course, can be carried on for as many dimensions as you want; the compiler just has to "remember" how big the steps will be.

Answer (score 0):

since you know the elements in each of the array(i.e 4),you can easily construct the bigger array having 16 elements....
arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4   and arr5(all the 4 arrays will be stored in it)
you can traverse the bigger array,and fill in the contents for smaller arrays

arr5-->[4 elements]arr1----------[4 elements]arr2--------[4 elements]arr3-------[4 elements]arr4==========[16 elements]

for(i=0;i<16;i++)//traversing the bigger array)
{

//for first array ,fill up the contents and increment the i,this would fill up the bigger array 
for(j=0;j<4;j++,i++)
arr5[i]=arr1[j];
similarly for other arrays as well

}